When to use У меня over У меня есть?
I happened to notice that for most sentences in Russian, you use У меня есть [noun] for I have. For example:
⦿ I have a dog. У меня есть собака.
But for some sentences, you use either У меня есть [noun] or just У меня [noun]:
⦿ I have a big dog. У меня большая собака.
⦿ I have a small dog. У меня есть маленькая собака.
This could just be an issue with the translation app that I use, but I would like to know when to or not to use есть in у меня (есть).

Omitting есть makes the clause rhematic (a comment) rather than thematic (a topic). The emphasis is not on the fact that you have something, but on clarifying what it is exactly that you have.
У меня есть большая собака means that you have a big dog and the news is that you have it.
У меня большая собака would probably be used to convey "mine is a big dog". It's already somehow established that you have a dog, and the news is that it's big.

Я не могу пойти пить пиво, у меня завтра экзамен.

"I can't go have a beer — I have an exam tomorrow". There's a reason I can't have the beer, and this reason is the exam.

Я не могу пойти пить пиво, у меня завтра есть экзамен.

"I can't go have a beer; I do have an exam tomorrow". I thought maybe I wouldn't have the exam, but it turns out I do.

"Завтра есть"--- фантастика. Возьмите другой пример.

С определённой интонацией, допустимо, нет?
В ситуации, когда вас пригласили пить пиво, но вы сказали, что сначала вам нужно проверить нет ли у вас завтра экзамена.
"[Ой,] я [всё-таки] не смогу пойти пить пиво, у меня завтра есть экзамен".

Либо "завтра экзамен" , либо "завтра будет экзамен".
